# Who is Derek Sherinian's neighbour in "Blood Of The Snake" hidden track?

Tags: prog-metal

In Derek Sherinian's album 'Blood Of The Snake' there is a hidden track after the last song finishes where Derek seems to be having something like a party and his neighbour knocks the door to complain about the noise. Who is the 'neighbour' and is he really Derek's neighbour?

Comment: Do you have the name of this bonus track?

Comment: @Bebs it has no name. You can hear it after waiting long enough after the last song (In the Summertime) ends.